# Averaging subsets of certain dimensions in a 4D matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, 4d

My problem stems from having difficulty conceptualizing 4D matrices (as opposed to 3D).
In MATLAB, I have data stored in a 5x5x7x54 matrix. The 5x5 part is symmetric across the diagonal and represents correlations in activity between 5 brain areas. The '7' represents 7 time points and the '54' represents 54 subjects of which there are 17 each in 3 groups (First 17 are Group1, next 17 are Group2, last 17 are Group3).

I would like to average each correlation value across the participant in each group but I want to do this separately for each time point. So for example, I want the average correlation values for the first 17 subjects for timepoint 1, then for timepoint 2, etc. Then I want the average correlation values for the middle 17 subjects for timepoint 1, etc.

In sum, I would have 7 5x5 matrices for each group (so 21 5x5 matrices total).

I am absolute crap at MATLAB so my initial way of thinking about solving this problem was to think of just dividing the matrix up in loops but I know that that will be both confusing and inefficient. Otherwise, though, I'm super lost because I'm having such a hard time conceptualizing the matrix itself.

Can anyone suggest a plan of action?

Comment: Use the `dim` argument to `mean` to average across the fourth dimension?  Like `mean(A(:,:,:,1:17), 4)`

Comment: This seems to work just as I want it to, thank you so much. I suppose I was worried that using the `dim` argument would somehow disregard the third dimension information so I just ended up with a single 5x5 matrix of averages, although I'm not sure why I thought this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Voigt's comment is on point, but one can do even a tad better. Since you want to compute the average for each group of subjects, let's separate the subject and group dimensions:

```
A = reshape(A, [5 5 7 17 3]);
```

Now you have a five-dimensional array, where the last two dimensions are "subject" and "group". Let's average across subjects:

```
m = mean(A, 4);
```

The result is an array with dimension 5 x 5 x 7 x 1 x 3. After averaging, the fourth dimension is a [singleton](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html). We can get rid of that:

```
m = squeeze(m);
```

After that, the average correlation matrix for timepoint `t` and group `g` is `m(:, :, t, g)`.

Comment: This ends up being quite helpful for other manipulations I am planning, so thank you so much.